# set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector

Tags: tomcat7

I am getting this error on tomcat7.

> INFO: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus
>   POST) for a single request ([10,000]) were detected. Any parameters
>   beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the
>   maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.

Can anyone tell me if I can modify `maxParameterCount` and if so, how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this (in the file server.xml):

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" maxParameterCount="1000000"/>
```

Look for the details:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

**Added**

The link to Tomcat 10
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: Can ypu please tell me in which file should I make this change? server.xml??

Comment: Thanks Michael..yes it was helpful...Can you tell me if such change can be made for WAS7 as well? "maxParamPerRequest" is there for WAS61...but i dnt have any idea for WAS7

Comment: Sorry, can not help you with WAS7. I recommend to ask a similar question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: @Michael. Thanks a lot. Save my a lot of time. :D

Comment: Hi, your answer is very helpful. I'm able to resolve one of our issue re this. Btw, is there any implication/negative effect on increasing the maxParameterCount? Thank you.

Comment: @Michael In which file I should put this code?

Comment: The file is server.xml.
The link to Tomcat 10
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: After changing the server.xml on tomcat the issue got resolved but when the application is accessed from web server (httpd) the same problem is occurring. is there any similar attribute available for httpd?