# Max number of request parameters reached in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that's using multi-upload to update sometimes large amounts of files 10K+. In those cases, I'm hitting this exception. I'm guessing it's looking at my "files" parameter and seeing that it's an array > 10K and flagging this exception. I'm also sending another parameter that's an array of strings that are associated with the list of files, its size being the number of files, > 10K

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([10,000]) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.addParameter(Parameters.java:204) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
```

I understand the exception, but I'm trying to figure out where in my `application.properties` I can adjust this. I've set `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.http.multipart.max-request-size` there. I'm not finding anything equivilant to the `maxParameterCount` in this [source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Also, assuming there's a way I can set it for the instance running locally with spring boot (tomcat embedded), will the change also work in the deploymenet environment, or does that require changing a tomcat configuration?

Update: I found a solution that works when running locally with spring boot. I assume since this is changing the Tomcat Embedded instance, that this wouldn't apply to a deployed full tomcat environment -- I am wondering if there's a solution that would work in both tomcat instances.

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatCustomizationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        final int maxHttpRequests = 50000;
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

        tomcatFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setMaxParameterCount(maxHttpRequests));

        return tomcatFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Connector is a Tomcat configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105549/set-the-maxparametercount-attribute-on-the-connector As to how to set it up with Spring Boot, not too sure, so not marking as dupe for this.

Comment: If you want it to work in a "real"/shared tomcat instance, you should change the container configs directly, not programmatically since those are server-wide (what if another deployed app wants 500 max params, and you want 20-thousand?). It would be done in `server.xml` by adding a `maxParameterCount=". . ."` to your `<Connector . . .>` definition.

Comment: You're saying that my app's code shouldn't be changing a server-wide setting, but it would be acceptable to set the server-wide config file?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.configure), you can add missing configuration yourself by extending the WebServerFactoryCustomizer:

> If a configuration key doesn’t exist for your use case, you should then look at WebServerFactoryCustomizer. You can declare such a component and get access to the server factory and the chosen web stack.

As there is no `server.tomcat.max-parameter-count` configuration yet, you can add it kind of the same way as OPs configuration code:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatCustomizationConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Value("${server.tomcat.max-parameter-count:10000}")
    private int maxParameterCount;

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setMaxParameterCount(maxParameterCount));
    }
}
```

*N.B. I actually found the solution at [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/4517808578/) blog.*