# Maximum number of parameters in HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring

I have an HTML page with a `<form>` which needs to have a lot of input elements (> 10000) and seems like a lot of them gets removed from the request when the form is submitted. So my models doesn't have necessary fields from the form.

Is there a limit on amount of inputs (select, input etc.) that can be present at the form at the same time?

I am using Spring rest API as a backend and if to evaluate request parameters map there are 10000 elements, which is a bit less then inputs count in my form.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I found my solution here :
[set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105549/set-the-maxparametercount-attribute-on-the-connector/17130848)

In fact, in some web servers, including Tomcat, there is a default limit of 10000 parameters that can be overrun by setting some specific parameter in the server configuration file.